# Webpage displays differently when viewed in a browser from the local machine than when viewed in a browser from the server

Tags: javascript, web, html5-canvas

I have the following web page, which when I view in a browser from my local computer, displays exactly as I intended it to. However, after copying that page to my filestore on the server (along with all of the supporting files it requires), and viewing it from the server by browsing to the URL at which it's located, I find that it is not displayed in the same way as when viewing it from my local computer.

The page I have is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  canvas{
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    background:#F5F5F5;
  }
</style>
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="drawDescriptionBoxes.js"></script>
<script>
/*Add the game elements' global variables */
var currentLevel = 1;
var totalLevels = 3;
var currentScore = 0;
var currentScorePositionX = 950;
var currentScorePositionY = 10;

/*Add code to draw images to random locations here */
    var imageX = Math.floor(Math.random()*950);
    var imageY = Math.floor(Math.random()*450);

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: "container",
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    });
    var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var canvas = imagesLayer.getCanvas();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    console.log("Foo ");

function loadImages(sources, callback){
    var imagesDir = "";
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;

    //console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (var src in sources){
        numImages++;
    }
    //console.log("Num Images " + numImages);

    var index=0;
    console.log("length " + sources.length);
    for (index=0;index < numImages ;index++){
        console.log(index);
        images[index] = new Image();
        images[index].src = sources[index];
        console.log("Adding " + sources[index]);
        callback(images[index]);
        console.log("images array length = " + images.length);
    }

    stage.add(imagesLayer); // should only be added once!!
    }

    function isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox){
        var ii = itemImage;
        var db = descriptionBox;
        if(ii.attrs.x > db.x - 20 && ii.attrs.x < db.x + 20 && ii.attrs.y > db.y - 20 && ii.attrs.y < db.y +20){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* This function draws the game elements */
    function drawGameElements(){
        /* Draw a line for the 'score bar'. */
        context.moveTo(0, 25);
            context.lineTo(1000, 25);
        context.stroke();

        /* Draw current level/ total levels on the left, and current score on the right. */
        context.font = "11pt Calibri"; /* Text font & size */
        context.strokeStyle = "black"; /* Font colour */
        context.strokeText(currentLevel + "/" + totalLevels, 10, 15);
        context.strokeText(currentScore, 750, 15);
    }

    function initStage(images){
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "container",
            width: 1000,
            height: 500
        });
        var descriptionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        //var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var allImages = [];
        var currentScore = 0;




        /*Draw the description boxes */

    }

  function drawImage(imageObj) {
    //var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var canvasImage = new Kinetic.Image({
      image: imageObj,
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
          // puts the image in teh middle of the canvas
          x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 50 / 2,
      draggable: true
    });

    // add cursor styling
    canvasImage.on('mouseover', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    });
    canvasImage.on('mouseout', function() {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    imagesLayer.add(canvasImage);
  }

    /*This code loads the images to the canvas when the browser window loads */
    window.onload = function(){
        var sources = {};
            sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
            sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
            sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
            sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
            sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
            sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
            sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
            sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
            sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
            sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

            sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
            sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
            sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
            sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
            sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

            sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
            sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
            sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
            sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
            sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
            sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
            sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
            sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

            sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
            sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
            sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

            sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
            sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
            sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
            sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
            sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
            sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
            sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
            sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

        loadImages(sources, drawImage);
        drawGameElements();
        drawDescriptionBoxes();
    };


    </script>


</head>
<body>

<section hidden>
<img id="startButton" src="images/startButton.png" alt="Start Button" width="179" height="180" href="javascript:drawLevelOneElements();"/>
<img id="box" src="images/box.png" alt="box.png" alt="Description Box" width="100" height="50" />

<img id="building" src="images/assets/building.png" alt="Asset" />
<img id="chair" src="images/assets/chair.gif" alt="Asset" />
<img id="drink" src="images/assets/drink.jpg" alt="Asset" />
<img id="food" src = "images/assets/food.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="fridge" src = "images/assets/fridge.png" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="land" src = "images/assets/land.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="money" src = "images/assets/money.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="oven" src = "images/assets/oven.jpg" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="table" src = "images/assets/table.gif" alt="Asset"/>
<img id="van" src = "images/assets/van.jpg" alt="Asset"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/expenses/direct/burger.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/expenses/direct/chips.png" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/expenses/direct/drink.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="franchiseFee" src = "images/expenses/direct/franchiseFee.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>
<img id="wages" src = "images/expenses/direct/wages.jpg" alt="Direct Expense"/>

<img id="admin" src = "images/expenses/indirect/admin.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="cleaners" src = "images/expenses/indirect/cleaners.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/expenses/indirect/electricity.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="insurance" src = "images/expenses/indirect/insurance.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="manager" src = "images/expenses/indirect/manager.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="rates" src = "images/expenses/indirect/rates.jpg" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="training" src = "images/expenses/indirect/training.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>
<img id="water" src = "images/expenses/indirect/water.gif" alt="Indirect Expense"/>

<img id="burger" src = "images/income/burger.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="chips" src = "images/income/chips.png" alt="Income"/>
<img id="drink" src = "images/income/drink.jpg" alt="Income"/>

<img id="creditors" src = "images/liabilities/creditors.gif" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="electricity" src = "images/liabilities/electricity.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="food" src = "images/liabilities/food.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="hirePurchase" src = "images/liabilities/hirePurchase.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="loan" src = "images/liabilities/loan.png" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="overdraft" src = "images/liabilities/overdraft.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="payeTax" src = "images/liabilities/payeTax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>
<img id="tax" src = "images/liabilities/tax.jpg" alt="Liability"/>


</section>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view it locally, it displays a canvas, with four 'description boxes' which have been drawn by the following function that's called from the JavaScript on the page (although the function itself is actually in a separate JS file):

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    context.drawDescriptionArea(70, 400, 120, 70);
    context.font = '25pt Calibri';
    context.strokeText('Asset', 90, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(300, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Liability', 310, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(540, 400, 120, 70);
    context.strokeText('Income', 550, 440);

    context.drawDescriptionArea(750, 400, 180, 70);
    context.strokeText('Expenditure', 760, 440);
```

However, when I view it from the server using the URL at which it's located, for some reason, the description boxes are not displayed on the canvas, and I don't understand why, since I have copied everything over from my local machine to the server, so it should all be there.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is you function in this file `<script src="drawDescriptionBoxes.js"></script>`?  Can you verify in your browser that the file actually loaded?

Comment: Yes, the function is in that file. I'm not sure what you mean? How would I verify that the file is actually loaded? It displays when I view it from my local machine (i.e. by right clicking on the index.html file, and opening it in a browser), so that means it must be loading the JS file... and I've copied everything across from my local machine to the server, so I would expect it to function in exactly the same way

Comment: I mean if you use Firebug or similar, you can look at the actual network information to see that you received the files with 200 response.

Comment: When viewing the Script in Firebug, I can see that `loadImages(sources, drawImage);
drawGameElements();
drawDescriptionBoxes();
}; ` is called at the end of my `window.onload()` function, so I assume that means that the file has loaded? Or if not, how do I check that in Firebug? But then in the console, it's telling me that drawDescriptionBoxes is not defined...

Comment: Just because you see the calls to the function, does not mean the function itself was loaded.  The calls to the function are part of your main source code for the page, so they should definitely show up.  Like I said look at the "net" panel in firebug to see all the requests that are made in order to load the page.  You will be able to see the secondary request for the javascript include with the function and determine if it was actually loaded (has a "200 OK" status code).

Comment: Ah Ok, in the net panel, I'm getting a 404 not found on `GET drawDescriptionBoxes.js` I'm wondering if this is because since the server is a Unix based machine, I noticed that where I've stored it on the server, the filename has become 'drawdescriptionboxes.js' i.e. no capitals... would renaming it in the code to refer to the file with caps work?

Comment: @someone2008 That would work.  Actullly the file name was probably always that, just in your windows environment where filenames are not case-sensitive it worked for you. Linux cares about case.  honestly I never use any uppercase letters in any filenames for code that needs to port across platforms for this specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file specified here:

```
<script src="drawDescriptionBoxes.js"></script>
```

is not loading.

Per discussion in comments above, this is because filename has capitalization issues in source code.